# User authentication in asp.net or mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

How do I check if the user changed their IP address by calling a method in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
Request.UserHostAddress()
```

Comment: i say for check user change his ip or not means to say any user change his ip for our site or not

Comment: You would store that IP associated with the user's identity, and then compare it later.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to get user ip:

```
public class UserIp
{
    private string _StrIpAddress;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the UserIp class.
    /// </summary>
    public UserIp()
    {            
        _StrIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (_StrIpAddress == null)
            _StrIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress can be used to get the IP addess. you can match userid with IP address. you can check either after user login (session_start) or at the begining of each page (page_load method).